# inline an input and set its width to fit the content in CSS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using jQuery [QueryBuilder](https://querybuilder.js.org/) plugin. I have an input in **Bootstrap 3** as below :
[image]

I want it to fit the content based on the width of the screen, on large monitors the input doesn't enlarge in width. I tried some css tricks but couldn't make it work.

I set

```
input {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

and the `div` containing the `input`

```
.rule-value-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

now the `input` fits the content but it's in separate line. I tried `display: inline-block !important;` as well with parents div but didn't work.

Any suggestions please what I am missing in my code ? Thank you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 


$('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
    
    filters: [ 
     { id: 'name',
      label: 'Name',
      type: 'string',
      operators: ['equal','contains'] }
    ]
 });   
 
 
});
```

```css
.rule-value-container {
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

input {
  min-width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://querybuilder.js.org/node_modules/sql-parser-mistic/browser/sql-parser.min.js"></script>


<div id="queryBuilder"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest trick is to use css calc() method to apply the width for standard resolution. Next  use media queries to adjust the width % for the resolutions you want to support.

```
.rule-value-container {
  width: calc(100% - 42%); /*Can use either % value or px */
  display: inline-block;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
   .rule-value-container {
    width: calc(100% - <new % value>);
  }
}
```

**Update**: Added jquery script to adjust the width.

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $('#queryBuilder').queryBuilder({
       filters: [ 
       { id: 'name',
         label: 'Name',
         type: 'string',
         operators: ['equal','contains'] 
       }
      ]
   });   
});

 // Alternate option
$(document).on("change","select.form-control",function() {
  let containerWidth = $('.rule-container').width();
  let ddOne = $(this).parent('.rule-filter-container').width();
  let that = this;
  setTimeout(function(){ 
    let ddTwo = $(that).parent('.rule-filter-container').siblings('.rule-operator-container').width();
    let delBtnWidth = $('.btn-danger').width();
    let totalWidth = (containerWidth - (ddOne + ddTwo + delBtnWidth)) - 45;
    $(that).parent('.rule-filter-container').siblings('.rule-value-container').width(totalWidth+'px');
  }, 50);
});
```

```css
.rule-value-container {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/css/query-builder.default.min.css">


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jQuery-QueryBuilder@2.5.2/dist/js/query-builder.standalone.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://querybuilder.js.org/node_modules/sql-parser-mistic/browser/sql-parser.min.js"></script>


<div id="queryBuilder"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but your solution is not working. The input width is not expanding according the screen size. There is still much white space between the input and the delete button

Comment: You need to add multiple media queries based on the resolutions you wanted to support. What are the screen sizes you are targeting?

Comment: it doesn't matter what size. I want the width to fit the content whenever a user uses different monitor size

Comment: @DevTN Updated the code with Jquery script to adjust the width based on container width